# Single call in .bashrc starting two daemon processes

Tags: centos, bashrc

I am using CentOS 6.6 and would like /OtagoHarbour/executables/inotifydropboxcopy to start as a daemon when I boot the computer and log in.  I put the following in ~/.bashrc

```
 # User specific aliases and functions
 /OtagoHarbour/executables/inotifydropboxcopy &
```

When I boot up the computer and enter

```
ps aux | grep inotifydropboxcopy
```

I get

```
500       1859  0.0  0.0   3268   732 ?        S    16:11   0:00 /OtagoHarbour/executables/inotifydropboxcopy
500       2175  0.0  0.0   3268   728 pts/0    S    16:11   0:00 /OtagoHarbour/executables/inotifydropboxcopy
500       2843  0.0  0.0   4356   728 pts/0    S+   17:12   0:00 grep inotifydropboxcopy
```

When I comment out /OtagoHarbour/executables/inotifydropboxcopy & in .bashrc and restart the computer

```
ps aux | grep inotifydropboxcopy
```

returns

```
500       2843  0.0  0.0   4356   728 pts/0    S+   17:12   0:00 grep inotifydropboxcopy
```

Can someone tell me how to start exactly 1 /OtagoHarbour/executables/inotifydropboxcopy  daemon process when I boot up the ocmputer and log in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24925947/1195751).

> .bashrc always executes everytime an interactive non-login bash instantiates so use .bash_profile instead so it would only run once during login to ssh. If the script or processes of the script summons bash, it would cause repeated summoning.

So instead of putting that line in `~/.bashrc` put it in `~/.bash_profile` and see if you only get 1 instance of `inotifydropboxcopy`.